# This folder (/2018-09-11_zilla.disk_image) will not delete!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, permissions, directory

2 days ago, when R. clicking on this folder, there was a "move to trash" option.  When I tried it would not work. When I picked any file contained within this folder (/2018-09-11_zilla.disk_image) and tried to delete, could not because 'do not have permission, I'm the owner.' Today when I right click on this folder, delete option is gone, but now can 'open in Terminal (in blue text, cursor on R. side), have tried, but unable to delete. I'm not skilled with using Terminal, but it has worked for me when I know what to enter.  I have rephrased this question because this folder has messed up my dual boot.  I can't boot Windows 10 from the grub, or BIOS 'boot menu.'  If I can get back to Windows 10, I will delete the the Ubuntu partition (& swap) and reinstall.

Comment: This should explain https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Answer (score 0):

The most probable answer is that you don't have permissions to delete that file right from Ubuntu, the steps to follow would be:

1. Find the folder in the Files app, right click and choose **Open In Terminal**
2. on the command line, type (press Enter after each line):

   cd ..
   ls -l
3. This should show a list of all folders with a few columns, what interests you are the first, third and fourth that state, respectively, the permissions (should have drwxr-xr-- or something like that), the owner and the group (these two should be your username both, probably).
   In case you are not the owner, you'll have to run:

   sudo chown -R youruser:youruser 2018-09-11_zilla.disk_image

If you show us what the ls -l command prints you we can help you more, in case this is no the issue at hand.

Comment: After I opened the folder in Terminal, and then typed in (after the folder title in blue text) "cd .. Is -IEnter" it came back with "Bash: cd: too many arguments"  Then I tried the next command you suggested, 1st as you wrote it, next substituting my user name for the word "user"  came back for both with "chown: invalid user: 'youruser:youruser' (and the other result had my user name sub'd in). Thanks for trying to help. I was in Windows yesterday and I so wish I had deleted the Ubuntu partition, so I could reinstall.  I didn't realize I would get locked out.

Comment: When I told you to type Enter I meant to press enter, sorry for my typo (not English). This way it will let you execute the commands

Comment: It's not your fault, I take everything literally when it comes instructions for Terminal.  I will try what you have said.

Comment: Unfortunately the results are the same as I wrote above (23 hrs ago).  It's weird that the 2nd thing (-R youruser:youruser...), I get my hopes up because it asks for my password, but then it's "invalid user."  And the same when I sub my actual user name for the words "user."  I'm a newbie to the concepts of 'permissions,' but it seems strange that as the 'owner' I'm not allowed to delete.  If I was to somehow change the permissions of this folder to 'read & write,' would I then be able to delete this folder?

Comment: I'm not sure why I was able to do this now, but I changed the permissions with the permissions tab: from read only to read and write, so I was able to delete all the files in this Clonezilla folder, but I still can't delete (now empty) folder even though it seemed I was able to change it's permissions.  Progress I guess.

Comment: You should be able to change the folder permissions the same way you did the files. If not, from the console, if you want to delete, you should be able to just ran **sudo rm -r 2018-09-11_zilla.disk_image** where you ran the other commands I told you. It should ask for your password because **sudo**  tells de terminal to run the following command with superuser permissions, so you have to authenticate because sudo can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I posted question I didn't realize that the real problem I had caused by accidentally saving a Clonezilla disk image file into my Ubuntu system folder is that it corrupted the efi boot partition.  After I made this 1st mistake I did correctly save a system disk image file to my external drive, it contained "my mistake," but it still turned out to be the way out of this mess.  On 9.12.18 I had booted into Windows 10, but I didn't realize if I restarted again I would get stuck in Ubuntu, which is what happened.  On Sun. 9.16.18 I decided my only chance was to restore the flawed disk image file, because I knew I would have ONE boot into Windows 10, and that's what I did.  Once in Windows I reset the PC and last night I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1, and everything is great again!  I guess if there is a silver lining it's that I feel confident with using Clonezilla, it's an amazing tool.  To everyone who took the time to help me I apologize, it took me time to figure out that using Terminal wasn't going to solve the problem.